# Override props with styled-components and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm using a component that has a property that is required.
I want to style that component with said property set and not being required to set it again when rendering. If I don't set it again Typescript complains.

The jist of what I want to do:

```
const Arrow = styled(<Icon icon={"ArrowRight"}/>)`
    ...
`;
```

And not being required to set `icon` when rendering.

If I do this

```
const Arrow = styled(Icon)`
    ...
`;

Arrow.defaultProps = {
    icon: "ArrowRight",
};
```

I still have to set `icon` when rendering.

Is there some way I can achieve this or is my only way out to modify props of Arrow with typescript-magic?

---

Using

- typescript 3.7.5
- react 16.12.0
- styled-components 5.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`styled-components` has an API named `attrs` so you can attach properties to DOM elements or components.

```
const Arrow = styled(Icon).attrs(props => ({
  icon: props.icon // or whatever you want here
}))`

`;
```

[Docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#attrs)

Comment: Thanks I though that `attrs` wouldn't solve the typescript-part aswell